# How to format all values before display

Tags: java, jsf

I have a problem relate to currency format. In the old source we have a lot of `fee value` to display on UI but they never formatted.

Now we want to format them all base on Locale before display.

The current code look something like this:

```
private BigDecimal userFee;

public void setUserFee(BigDecimal userFee) {
    this.userFee = userFee;
}

public BigDecimal getUserFee() {
    return userFee;
}
```

On jsp page

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{beanName.userFee}" />
```

The problem is there are too many `fee value` dispay on many page. The only solution I can see is format them one by one but seem like it's not a good choice.

I have two questions:

1. The best way to format currency in my case.
2. Is there any other
       solution better than format all `fee value` one by one.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use h:outputText, and place `<f:convertNumber type="currency"/>` inside each one?  See [Using the Standard Converters: Using NumberConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-page-core001.htm#JEETT00933).

Comment: Because in future we plan to shorter number to display like 300.000 to 300k.

Comment: It sounds like you should write your own [Coverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/Converter.html) class for your application, and have each currency h:outputText refer to it.

Answer (score -1):

What i've done in a recent project is create a class that wraps the BigDecimal, and override its tostring to format it as I want.  This extra layer may cause problems for you depending on your layers of abstraction.

```
public class Currency implements Serializable
{
    private BigDecimal value;

    public Currency(String val)
    {
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(val))
            this.value = new BigDecimal(val).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    }

    public Currency(Double val)
  {
        if(val!=null)
            this.value = new BigDecimal(val).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  }

    public Currency(Float val)
  {
        if(val!=null)
            this.value = new BigDecimal(val).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
  }

    public BigDecimal getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
  public String toString()
    {
        if(value==null) return "";
        return new DecimalFormat("0.00").format(value);
    }
}
```